# Why my react build app not working in Namecheap server?

Tags: reactjs, hosting, shared-hosting, namecheap

Recently, I made a website using react and hosted on Hostinger and it worked properly. Then I shifted to Namecheap for some reason. And the same build file(which I uploaded on Hostinger) worked in Namecheap too. But when I re-upload my new build file with some update of my website, it crashed. It show's only blank page. Sometimes it working in some browser and sometimes not.

The build file which I re-uploaded on Namecheap working on netlify server (`easytopupbdtest.netlify.app`) but not on Namecheap. Then I thought that Namecheap has problem maybe, that's why my application is not running. Then again I changed my IP address and nameservers and pointed to the Hostinger. But it also not worked! I mean, the same build file which worked before I shift to the Namecheap.

Image of the main website when it is hosted on Namecheap server:

[image]

Comment: Please post the code or error as text in question, not an image.

Comment: You have a syntax error in your JavaScript, but you don't post your JavaScript code.  It is impossible to help you figure out what is wrong without that.

Answer (score 0):

Check your .htaccess file. That should be where the error is coming from that it's not displaying.

If you don't have a .htaccess file, try to create one. And if you have one, try to fix it.